# PHP - How to create/change value of environment variables

Tags: php

I don't know if it is possible to create environment variables in php. The method [putenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) is not of use as the docs say `At the end of the request the environment is restored to its original state.` Any help?

Comment: That's what all environment variables are.  Do you want them user specific or for the entire app?

Comment: Tell us what other behavior you wish then...